# How to store one more field based on input with Laravel saving event?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a column in `MySQL` which has some integer stored and what I need is when I am saving (creating or updating) the model, calculate some modified data and store it in another column. I want to use `saving` event for that, but don't know how to do that.

I have tried to add the following code to the `AppServiceProvider` but it does not do anything.

```
Report::saving(function($report){
    if(!is_null($report->year_month)){
        $date = Carbon::parse($report->year_month . "-1");
        $report->first_date = $date;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the model events in laravel. Throw something like this in the model:

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function($thisModel){
        $thisModel->otherField = 'your value';
    }
}
```